# ReportViewer is not being showed starting at the top

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm having a problem with a reportViewer. It works correctly (it show the correct information) but the reportViewer is displayed starting on the last position of itself before closed.

For example: if I run my program, the first report is showed starting in the top, I scroll until the middle of the page, then close the windowsForm and regenerate the same report (with the same or other parameter) and it starts in the middle of the page. It don't let me scroll to the top because the middle of the page is its new top.

Hope someone could help me. 
Sorry for my poor english.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and obviusly the reportviewer is contained in a Windows Form (this one don't have any particular change about scroll or anything).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `Me.dispose` in your form's `form_closing` event.

example:

```
Private Sub frmPrint_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Me.Dispose()
End Sub
```